# SCPlugin icons and menu

Tags: subversion

I installed SCPlugin on my mac for subversion. It works fine but I don't see the icons show status of my files. And I don't have SCPlugin's options in my right click menu bar. Any idea how to fix these?

Comment: Which version of Mac OS X do you have installed?

Comment: I have Lion, but I used to have snow leopard.

Answer (score 1):

for the menu bar, there is a workaround that you can start from the top bar of your finder window. it's almost as good as with the right-click context menu.

http://scplugin.tigris.org/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=1525&dsMessageId=2441924

Because of the invisible icons I am also searching for help.

Comment: While this may answer the question, [it is best](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to summarize the contents of the link and provide the link for reference. Links have a tendency disappear over time, leaving a non-applicable answer for those who may stumble upon your answer in the future.